# Excel to search 2 columns that have multiple the same but combined have only one output

Tags: excel, search, match

I have a unique building number and a unique room number.

But I have 240 buildings and looking to reference a unique space number.

Example :-

```
Building No. Room Number Unique reference
1                101       X132
1                102       A123
1                103       C123
1                104       B123 
2                101       G123 
2                102       D343
3                101       X111
```

So if i use Building 1 and room 103 = C123 been struggling with this for 24 hours so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Enter as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH("1"&"103",A:A&B:B,0),0)
```

Change 1 and 103 to cell references and limit the columns.

Comment: A solution that worked this morning was to craete a CONCATENATE column with A+B columns combined (Call this column C and insert before unique reference named Array Dave) then=VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(A2&B2),Dave,2,FALSE)